# loop through all classes that extend a certain class

Tags: java, class

What I would like to do is loop through all of the classes that are extending a class i have called Cmd.

For instance, what I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
for (Class<?> c : classesExtendingSuperclass) {
    cmds.put(c, c.getName());
}
```

Thanks.

Edit: I can't use reflections in my project, if I do it will complicate everything when using the program. I can't use Reflections due to the performance downsides in the project.

Comment: Are the performance implications worth more to you than the time it would take to develop and test your own implementation of it, along side the actual *use* of it?

Comment: @Makoto Yes, the performance matters. This is for bukkit (minecraft server software) and reflections is known to lag and have performance issues with the software, which is something I don't want.

Comment: Honestly, this smells a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Could you explain what your intention is with this code?  Perhaps you'd get a better answer instead of it being confused for a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly , I think this is what you are looking for :

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("com.mycompany");    
Set<Class<? extends MyInterface>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class);
```

Comment: I can't use reflections in my project, if I do it will complicate everything when using the program.

Comment: @Banjo226 It's not Java's class, note that it's the `Reflections`.

Comment: I think that OP should mention that it's a 3rd party library.

Comment: I know its not part of the JDK, and I know its a library. What I was saying is I can't use Reflections due to the performance downsides for it in the project I am doing.